# How to debug qt project in xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, qmake, lldb

I've got a Qt Creator project that I need to run as root, and which I need to debug. Root debugging is apparently difficult and unreliable in Qt Creator, so I used qmake with -spec macx-xcode to generate an xcode project, hoping to debug in xcode instead.

I had to change C++ standard library to libstdc++ to get it to link, but otherwise it builds and runs fine.

However, no breakpoints are hit and the Debug Navigator says "No Debug Session" while the program is running. Attempting to attach to the process when it's already running just makes xcode say "Finished running $my_app" and does not attach, though the process is still running.

I suspect I'm trying to debug a release build. Can anyone tell me what I need to do with qmake to generate a debuggable xcode project? Or what I need to do in xcode to get debugging working?

I'm new to OSX and Qt, as you may have guessed.

(This is on OS X 10.8.5, XCode 5.1.1, Qt 4.8.6)

EDIT: the command I'm using to get qmake to generate the xcodeproj is: `"/opt/Qt-4.8.6/bin/qmake" ~/path_to_proj/qtproj.pro -r -spec macx-xcode CONFIG+=x86_64`

EDIT 2: The source Qt Creator project builds debug and release configurations correctly.

Comment: maybe in your `pro` file set `CONFIG = debug`

Comment: Thanks. I tried setting CONFIG=debug at the end of the .pro file, but the resulting xcodeproj is missing a lot - stuff like the Qt frameworks paths weren't exported and the project will not build without manual fixing up lots of paths.

Comment: CONFIG += debug (not CONFIG = debug), else you remove a whole lot of other things.